# What is fast, compact representation of tree structures that prevents cache misses?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures, language-agnostic

Graphical applications often represent images as flat arrays, instead of bidimensional arrays. If I'm not mistaken, this is done because flat arrays are much faster as they're compact and avoid cache misses. Example:

```
dimensional_array = [[1,2],[3,4],[4,5]]
four = dimensional_array[1,1]

flat_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
four = flat_array[1 + 2*1]
```

Is there a similar (or not) representation of free-form trees that allows for the same kind of performance gain?

```
free_form_tree = [[1,2,3],4,5,[[6,7],8]]
```

Comment: You do realize that in most languages, 1D and 2D arrays are implemented with exactly the same memory footprint and access time?  You may be thinking of nested and/or jagged arrays instead of 2D arrays.

Comment: @RBarryYoung This is true for many languages, but not for Java, for example - it only has nested arrays.

Answer (score 3):

If your tree is fairly complete (or you don't care as much about wasting space) and can fit into memory then you can store the tree in an array. You can use the same formula that an array based heap uses to "search" the tree.

- root is at index 0
- Children are always at indices (2*i + 1) and (2*i + 2) where i is
  your current index.
- Their parent is floor((i − 1) ∕ 2) where i is a child's index.

[Storing binary tree as an array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Methods_for_storing_binary_trees).

Also, see heap details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation).

Comment: The normal array representation of heap is not memory-friendly. Accessing 2*i+1 and 2*i+2 is most likely accessing another memory block, so traversing the tree will involve a lot of cache misses. B-trees is designed to overcome this problem.

Comment: @justhalf It is, however, compact, and it does prevent cache misses at the last few levels. It's also simple and fast to go up/down, in contrast to some more complicated schemes. Yes, B-trees are good, but the Ahnentafel layout is not terrible either.

Answer (score 1):

You can read up on [B-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree).

It is designed to read a block of its data from memory, thereby increasing memory performance.

You can look up more on Google using this query: "Cache oblivious tree" to get more links such as [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devdev/archive/2007/06/12/cache-oblivious-data-structures.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a postorder or perorder representation of tree along with inorder representation but again then if there is change in tree then you recompute then in O(n) which is expensive for small speed up. Other implementations like B-tree or advance hybrid datastructure are complex to implement and not worthy of your time for relatively small speed up. Because all operations in tree are O(logn) for balanced tree so cache can only give speed up by some constant factor which is insignificant compared to O(logN)